# SMS Tracking for a Mobile

Tags: sms, geolocation, tracking

i want know, where is my partner ( located where ), or How can I check on which Basestation in a city is it logged  etc..

REgards

Ben

Answer (score 3):

You simply can't unless you work for the mobile service provider, have full security clearance, and don't mind losing your job.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have physical access to the device yes. There are several apps that do this. Some that aimed at parents that aren't sneaky about it Obviously reporting stats. then there are apps requiring root access that hide themselves well. With sufficient skill and phones cabanle of being rooted you can take an existing app on the phone dump it uncompile the app and add remote access code. Like androrat.

Comment: Even with the antenna ID, how would they know where it is located?